# What is the order of evaluation of conditions combining AND/OR in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a query combining AND and OR conditions without parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 OR c = 3;
```

How does PostgreSQL evaluate these conditions? Like `(a = 1 AND b = 2) OR c = 3` or `a = 1 AND (b = 2 OR c = 3)`. I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Note: I'm not purposefully writing an ambiguous query like this. I'm building a tool where the user could potentially create a query like that.

Note 2: If it makes any difference, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 in one instance and 11 in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AND` is stronger than `OR`, so:

`a AND b OR c == (a AND b) OR c`

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4ba11a1a4b580fd4b2cc41ab4050dd53)

```
a  | b  | c  | a AND b OR c | (a AND b) OR c | a AND (b OR c)
:- | :- | :- | :----------- | :------------- | :-------
f  | f  | f  | f            | f              | f       
f  | f  | t  | t            | t              | f       
f  | t  | f  | f            | f              | f       
f  | t  | t  | t            | t              | f       
t  | f  | f  | f            | f              | f       
t  | f  | t  | t            | t              | t       
t  | t  | f  | t            | t              | t       
t  | t  | t  | t            | t              | t
```

That, of course, means in your case:

```
a = 1 AND b = 2 OR c = 3    ==    (a = 1 AND b = 2) OR c = 3
```

Comment: And by stronger, you mean it's always evaluated first, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a defined order for binding operators, meaning which will be applied before another. It is very similar in most programming languages. Lostgres documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-precedence.html